# JPA EntityNotFoundException. How to query without considering relationship mapping using JPA Criteria query

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria, jpa-2.1

I have a Product entity. One product can be a child of another. The relationship is mapped with OneToMany as follows.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentProd")
private Set<Products> childProd = new HashSet<>();

@ManyToOne
@JsonIgnoreProperties("childProd")
private Products parentProd;
```

The *parent_product_id* column generated from this mapping somehow contains invalid parent_ids. Hence I am getting the following error when i try to query all products using JPA criteria query.

> javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.test.Products with id 101
> at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:162)
> at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:234)

How to write a criteria query to select all Product entities without considering the parent_child relation?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Products implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "productName")
    private String productName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentProd")
    private Set<Products> childProd = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("childProd")
    private Products parentProd;

    //Getters And Setters
}
```

Comment: would you please show your entities?

Comment: @Rafa Added the entity in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the oneToMany annotation this way:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parentProd")
```

Here fetch = FetchType.Lazy means that data will not be fetched if you don't ask it explicitly.

Comment: Still getting the same error. But if I provide the fetchtype lazy in @ManyToOne, No error.

Comment: You need to put on the side that you dont need its data